# how to union and groupby in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to get contact id who was send chat or was i send chat to him
with native query i can get result but when i implement in laravel its going difficult 
this my native query

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (
    select `to` from messages where `from` = 2 group by `to`
    union
    select `from` from messages where `to` = 2 group by `from`
    )
```

what i find difficult is how union after group by or group by after union with make same column number, i using merge but the result is wrong
this what i have try in laravel

```
$to = Message::select('to')->where('from',auth()->id())->groupBy('to')->get();
$from = Message::select('from')->where('to',auth()->id())->groupBy('from')->get();

$tofrom = $to->merge($from);
dd($tofrom);
```

please if any body can help

Answer (score 0):

`merge()` is the method of collection. Not the Eloquent Builder or Query Builder.

However, It think you want to find user.id in the array.

You can convert the collection to array:

```php
$to = Message::where('from',auth()->id())->groupBy('to')->pluck('to');
$from = Message::where('to',auth()->id())->groupBy('from')->pluck('from');
$tofrom = $to->merge($from)->toarray();

User::whereIn('id', $tofrom)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unions are described in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#unions). To achieve your specific requirements you can do:

```
$final = User::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $from = Message::select('from')->where('from',auth()->id())->groupBy('from');
    $query->from('messages')->where('to',auth()->id())->groupBy('to')->union($from);
})->get();
```

Disclaimer: I have not actually tested this but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

oh finally i got the answer this is code

```
$contacts = User::select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.profile_image')
            ->join('messages',function($join){
                $join->on('users.id','messages.from');
                $join->orOn('users.id','messages.to');
                })
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('messages.from',auth()->id())->orWhere('messages.to',auth()->id());         
                })
            ->groupBy('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.profile_image')
            ->get();
```